# Почему в QOpenGLWidget не используется заданный по умолчанию QSurfaceFormat?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Я пытаюсь вывести на экран изображение в формате `RGB30`.

- Система: `Windows 10 x64`
- Версия `Qt`: `5.12.1 msvc2017_64`
- Видеокарта: `Quadro P400`
- Монитор: `NEC MD211C2` (Проверял бэнчмарком от `NEC` - 10-бит отрабатывает)

При создании приложения `Qt`, задаю формат поверхности:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(32);
    format.setRedBufferSize (10);
    format.setGreenBufferSize (10);
    format.setBlueBufferSize (10);
    format.setAlphaBufferSize(0);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
    format.setVersion(4, 6);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Затем вручную создаю виджет унаследованный от `QOpenGLWidget` и размещаю в лэйауте, передавая в конструкторе виджета сгенерированный `QByteArray`, представляющий собой данные изображения в формате `RGB30 (10-10-10-x)`.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QtEndian>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    width = 2048;
    height = 600;

    QByteArray *arr = gen30bitImgArr(width, height);
    ogl10 = new MyOGL(this, arr);
    ui->vLout->addWidget(ogl10);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QByteArray *MainWindow::gen30bitImgArr(int width, int height)
{
    QByteArray *arr = new QByteArray();
    QBuffer buffer(arr);
    buffer.open (QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream out(&buffer);

    uint32_t rgb30color = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
        for (uint32_t pixel = 0; static_cast<int>(pixel)< 1024; ++pixel) {
            for (int chanel = 0; chanel < 3; ++chanel) {
                rgb30color |= pixel;
                chanel == 2? 0 : rgb30color <<= 10;
            }
            rgb30color = qToBigEndian(rgb30color);
            out << rgb30color;
            out << rgb30color;
            rgb30color = 0;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

В самом `MyOGL`-виджете (основанном на примере `qopenglwidget`), я создаю прямоугольник и пытаюсь на нем отобразить `QOpenGLTexture` в формате `GL_RGB10_A2`. Вот тут и начинаются проблемы, если я настраиваю текстуру под 8-битный массив (его я исключил из примера), то все корректно отображается (не факт, мне показалось, что не доводятся до максимума на краях прямоугольника черный и белый цвета), но стоит все перевести в режим отображения 10-бит, как тут-же вместо прямоугольника отображается черный цвет. Я долго мучился перебирая все возможные комбинации параметров подходящих под мою задачу, а потом решил посмотреть что у меня в `this->format();`. Оказывается, что в конструкторе `MyOGL` в качестве `QSurfaceFormat` выступает тот формат, что я указал в качестве дефолтного, с 10'тью битами на каждый канал, однако, уже в `initializeGL()`, он сменяется на какой-то неведомый, с 8'мью битами на канал...
В какой момент происходит замена, я не понимаю. В документации, сколько ни копался, я не нашел объяснения. Привожу `MyOGL`:

**myogl.h**

```
#ifndef MYOGL_H
#define MYOGL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLShader>
#include <QOpenGLTexture>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>


class MyOGL : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyOGL(QWidget *parent = nullptr, const QByteArray *imgArr = nullptr);
    ~MyOGL() override;

protected:
    void initializeGL() override;
    void paintGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;

private:
    void makeObject();

    const QByteArray *imgData;

    qreal m_fAngle;
    qreal m_fScale;
    QVector<QVector3D> m_vertices;
    QOpenGLShader *m_vshader;
    QOpenGLShader *m_fshader;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram *m_program;
    QOpenGLTexture *m_texture;
    QOpenGLBuffer m_vbo;
    int m_vertexAttr;
    int m_texCoordAttr;
    int m_textureUniform;
    QColor m_background = QColor(30, 30, 30);

};

#endif // MYOGL_H
```

**myogl.cpp**

```
#include "myogl.h"
#include "qdebug.h"


MyOGL::MyOGL(QWidget *parent, const QByteArray *imgArr)
    : QOpenGLWidget(parent),
      m_program(nullptr),
      m_texture(nullptr)
{
    qDebug()<<"------------Start constructor-----------";
    this->setTextureFormat (GL_RGB10_A2);
    imgData = imgArr;

    qDebug()<<this->format()<<"\n";
    qDebug()<<this->format().renderableType()<<"\n";
    qDebug()<<this->textureFormat()<<"\n";
    qDebug()<<QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat()<<"\n";
    qDebug()<<"------------END constructor-----------\n";

}

MyOGL::~MyOGL()
{
    makeCurrent();
    delete m_texture;
    delete m_program;
    delete m_vshader;
    delete m_fshader;
    m_vbo.destroy();
    doneCurrent();
}

void MyOGL::initializeGL()
{
    qDebug()<<"----------Start Initalization-----------";
    qDebug()<<this->format()<<"\n";
    qDebug()<<this->format().renderableType()<<"\n";
    qDebug()<<this->textureFormat()<<"\n";
    qDebug()<<QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat()<<"\n";

    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    m_texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
    m_texture->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGB10A2);
    m_texture->setSize(2048, 600);
    m_texture->setMipLevels(1);
    m_texture->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA,
                               QOpenGLTexture::UInt32_RGB10A2);
    m_texture->setData(0,
                       QOpenGLTexture::RGBA,
                       QOpenGLTexture::UInt32_RGB10A2,
                       imgData->constData());

    m_vshader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
    const char *vsrc2 =
        "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
        "attribute mediump vec4 texCoord;\n"
        "varying mediump vec4 texc;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = vertex;\n"
        "    texc = texCoord;\n"
        "}\n";
    m_vshader->compileSourceCode(vsrc2);

    m_fshader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment);
    const char *fsrc2 =
        "uniform sampler2D tex;\n"
        "varying mediump vec4 texc;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, texc.st);\n"
        "}\n";
    m_fshader->compileSourceCode(fsrc2);

    m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram;
    m_program->addShader(m_vshader);
    m_program->addShader(m_fshader);
    m_program->link();

    m_vertexAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("vertex");
    m_texCoordAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("texCoord");
    m_textureUniform = m_program->uniformLocation("tex");

    m_fAngle = 0;
    m_fScale = 1;

    const int vertexCount = m_vertices.count();
    QVector<GLfloat> buf;
    buf.resize(vertexCount * 3 * 2);
    GLfloat *p = buf.data();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        *p++ = m_vertices[i].x();
        *p++ = m_vertices[i].y();
        *p++ = m_vertices[i].z();
    }
}

void MyOGL::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(m_background.redF(),
                 m_background.greenF(),
                 m_background.blueF(),
                 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    //glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    m_program->bind();
    makeObject();
    m_program->release();


    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);


    update();
}

void MyOGL::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}

void MyOGL::makeObject()
{
    m_texture->bind();
    if (!m_vbo.isCreated()) {
        static GLfloat afVertices[] = {

            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,

            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f

        };

        static GLfloat afTexCoord[] = {
            0.25f, 0.25f,
            0.25f, 0.75f,
            0.75f, 0.25f,

            0.75f, 0.75f,
            0.75f, 0.25f,
            0.25f, 0.75f

        };

        m_vbo.create();
        m_vbo.bind();
        m_vbo.allocate(30 * sizeof(GLfloat));
        m_vbo.write(0, afVertices, sizeof(afVertices));
        m_vbo.write(sizeof(afVertices), afTexCoord, sizeof(afTexCoord));
        m_vbo.release();
    }

    m_program->setUniformValue(m_textureUniform, 0); // use texture unit 0

    m_program->enableAttributeArray(m_vertexAttr);
    m_program->enableAttributeArray(m_texCoordAttr);

    m_vbo.bind();
    m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_vertexAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_texCoordAttr, GL_FLOAT,
                                  6 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 2);
    m_vbo.release();

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    m_program->disableAttributeArray(m_vertexAttr);
    m_program->disableAttributeArray(m_texCoordAttr);
}
```

Так же, прилагаю вывод в консоль и результат вызова `qtdiag.exe`, хочу обратить ваше внимание на `Buffer Size (RGBA) 8,8,8,8`. Почему так, ведь карта поддерживает 10,10,10,2 , а монитор переведен в режим `10-bit`?

**qDebug**

```
------------Start constructor-----------
QSurfaceFormat(version 4.6, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 32, redBufferSize 10, greenBufferSize 10, blueBufferSize 10, alphaBufferSize 0, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 

QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL 

32857 

QSurfaceFormat(version 4.6, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 32, redBufferSize 10, greenBufferSize 10, blueBufferSize 10, alphaBufferSize 0, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 

------------END constructor-----------

----------Start Initalization-----------
QSurfaceFormat(version 4.6, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(DeprecatedFunctions), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 

QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL 

32857 

QSurfaceFormat(version 4.6, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 32, redBufferSize 10, greenBufferSize 10, blueBufferSize 10, alphaBufferSize 0, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 

----------End Initalization-----------
```

**qtdiag.exe**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.253]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qtdiag.exe
Qt 5.12.1 (x86_64-little_endian-llp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by MSVC 2017) on "windows"
OS: Windows 10 (10.0) [winnt version 10.0.17763]

Architecture: x86_64; features: SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2

Environment:

Features: QT_NO_EXCEPTIONS

Library info:
  PrefixPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64
  DocumentationPath: D:\Qt\Docs\Qt-5.12.1
  HeadersPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\include
  LibrariesPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\lib
  LibraryExecutablesPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin
  BinariesPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin
  PluginsPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\plugins
  ImportsPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\imports
  Qml2ImportsPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\qml
  ArchDataPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64
  DataPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64
  TranslationsPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\translations
  ExamplesPath: D:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.12.1
  TestsPath: D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\tests
  SettingsPath:

Standard paths [*...* denote writable entry]:
  DesktopLocation: "Desktop" *C:\Users\dogrt\Desktop*
  DocumentsLocation: "Documents" *C:\Users\dogrt\Documents*
  FontsLocation: "Fonts" *C:\Windows\Fonts*
  ApplicationsLocation: "Applications" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs*
  MusicLocation: "Music" *C:\Users\dogrt\Music*
  MoviesLocation: "Movies" *C:\Users\dogrt\Videos*
  PicturesLocation: "Pictures" *C:\Users\dogrt\Pictures*
  TempLocation: "Temporary Directory" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local\Temp*
  HomeLocation: "Home" *C:\Users\dogrt*
  AppLocalDataLocation: "Application Data" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local\QtProject\qtdiag* C:\ProgramData\QtProject\qtdiag D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data\QtProject\qtdiag
  CacheLocation: "Cache" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local\QtProject\qtdiag\cache*
  GenericDataLocation: "Shared Data" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local* C:\ProgramData D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data
  RuntimeLocation: "Runtime" *C:\Users\dogrt*
  ConfigLocation: "Configuration" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local\QtProject\qtdiag* C:\ProgramData\QtProject\qtdiag D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data\QtProject\qtdiag
  DownloadLocation: "Download" *C:\Users\dogrt\Downloads*
  GenericCacheLocation: "Shared Cache" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local\cache*
  GenericConfigLocation: "Shared Configuration" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local* C:\ProgramData D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data
  AppDataLocation: "Application Data" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtdiag* C:\ProgramData\QtProject\qtdiag D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data\QtProject\qtdiag
  AppConfigLocation: "Application Configuration" *C:\Users\dogrt\AppData\Local\QtProject\qtdiag* C:\ProgramData\QtProject\qtdiag D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data D:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\data\QtProject\qtdiag

File selectors (increasing order of precedence):
  ru_RU windows winnt

Network:

SSL is not supported.

Platform capabilities: ThreadedPixmaps OpenGL ThreadedOpenGL WindowMasks MultipleWindows ForeignWindows NonFullScreenWindows NativeWidgets WindowManagement RasterGLSurface AllGLFunctionsQueryable

Style hints:
  mouseDoubleClickInterval: 500
  mousePressAndHoldInterval: 800
  startDragDistance: 10
  startDragTime: 500
  startDragVelocity: 0
  keyboardInputInterval: 400
  keyboardAutoRepeatRate: 32
  cursorFlashTime: 1060
  showIsFullScreen: 0
  showIsMaximized: 0
  passwordMaskDelay: 0
  passwordMaskCharacter: U+25CF
  fontSmoothingGamma: 1.2
  useRtlExtensions: 0
  setFocusOnTouchRelease: 0
  tabFocusBehavior: Qt::TabFocusAllControls
  singleClickActivation: 0

Additional style hints (QPlatformIntegration):
  ReplayMousePressOutsidePopup: 1

Theme:
  Platforms requested : windows
            available : snap,flatpak,xdgdesktopportal
  Styles requested    : WindowsVista,Windows
         available    : windowsvista,Windows,Fusion
  System font         : "MS Shell Dlg 2" 8
  Native file dialog

Fonts:
  General font : "MS Shell Dlg 2" 8
  Fixed font   : "Courier New" 9
  Title font   : "MS Shell Dlg 2" 8
  Smallest font: "MS Shell Dlg 2" 8

Palette:
  QPalette::WindowText: #ff000000
  QPalette::Button: #fff0f0f0
  QPalette::Light: #ffffffff
  QPalette::Midlight: #ffe3e3e3
  QPalette::Dark: #ffa0a0a0
  QPalette::Mid: #ffa0a0a0
  QPalette::Text: #ff000000
  QPalette::BrightText: #ffffffff
  QPalette::ButtonText: #ff000000
  QPalette::Base: #ffffffff
  QPalette::Window: #fff0f0f0
  QPalette::Shadow: #ff696969
  QPalette::Highlight: #ff0078d7
  QPalette::HighlightedText: #ffffffff
  QPalette::Link: #ff0000ff
  QPalette::LinkVisited: #ffff00ff
  QPalette::AlternateBase: #ffe9e7e3
  QPalette::NoRole: #ff000000
  QPalette::ToolTipBase: #ffffffdc
  QPalette::ToolTipText: #ff000000
  QPalette::PlaceholderText: #80000000

Screens: 1, High DPI scaling: inactive
# 0 "\\.\DISPLAY1" Depth: 32 Primary: yes
  Manufacturer:
  Model:
  Serial number:
  Geometry: 1600x1200+0+0 Available: 1600x1160+0+0
  Physical size: 432x324 mm  Refresh: 60 Hz Power state: 0
  Physical DPI: 94.0741,94.0741 Logical DPI: 96,96 Subpixel_None
  DevicePixelRatio: 1 Pixel density: 1
  Primary orientation: 2 Orientation: 2 Native orientation: 0 OrientationUpdateMask: 0

Dynamic GL LibGL Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer: Quadro P400/PCIe/SSE2
Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 391.35
Shading language: 4.60 NVIDIA
Format: Version: 4.6 Profile: 2 Swap behavior: 2 Buffer size (RGBA): 8,8,8,8 Depth buffer: 24 Stencil buffer: 8
Profile: None (QOpenGLFunctions_4_6)


Vulkan instance available
Supported instance extensions:
  VK_EXT_debug_report, version 9
  VK_EXT_display_surface_counter, version 1
  VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2, version 1
  VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2, version 1
  VK_KHR_surface, version 25
  VK_KHR_win32_surface, version 6
  VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities, version 1
  VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities, version 1
  VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities, version 1
  VK_NV_external_memory_capabilities, version 1
  VK_EXT_debug_utils, version 1
Supported layers:
  VK_LAYER_NV_optimus, version 1, spec version 1.0.65, NVIDIA Optimus layer
  VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation, version 1, spec version 1.0.92, LunarG Standard Validation Layer
Available physical devices:
  API version 1.0.65, vendor 0x10DE, device 0x1CB3, Quadro P400, type 2, driver version 391.140.0


GPU:
         Card name         : NVIDIA Quadro P400
       Driver Name         : nvldumdx.dll
    Driver Version         : 23.21.13.9135
         Vendor ID         : 0x10DE
         Device ID         : 0x1CB3
         SubSys ID         : 0x11BE10DE
       Revision ID         : 0x00A1
C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m_texture->setData(0,
                       QOpenGLTexture::RGBA,
                       QOpenGLTexture::UInt32_RGB10A2,
                       imgData->constData());
```

Мне кажется ошибка здесь
Если я не ошибаюсь ты передашь RGBA как internal firmat, поэтому внутренний формат текстуры меняется. см. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml